# iOS - How to reusue a UIView in different UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, swift3

I am working on a `UItableViewController`, where there can be five types of `UITableViewCell`. A major part of each type of cell is common. I can implement these part for all five cells but I would like to make a reusable view and use it inside all the cells. What is the best way to design and implement this requirement?

For example, In Facebook feed, there can be many types of posts. But the like/comment/share panel at the bottom of each post is same. How can I implement these different types of cells keeping like/comment/share panel in a single place on Xcode.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Subclass `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Can you explain it a little on the answer section? Thanks @CodeDifferent

Comment: Create a UIView (Xib or Programmatically whatever is easy for you). I'll recommend creating a function which returns UIView which is common for each cell.
And When you are calling "cellForRowAt" . Add that UIview as  subview of the ContentView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using storyboard**

What you can do is subclass the `UIView` that will contain all the common features.

For example:

```
class ViewWithBorder : UIView{

   //any view that you apply this class on in storyboard will
   //have the following properties assigned to it
    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

       //programmatically add buttons and whatever you desire to this view here
    }
}
```

Now in your storyboard, you have a Prototype cell created, just add a `UIView` inside the cell and set its class to `viewWithBorder`. All the properties assigned to it in `awakeFromNib` will be added to that view at run time.

**Note:** If you create the view programmatically and not using storyboard, you will have to override `initWithCoder`

**OR**

Create *xib* for the new `UIView` that will be common across all the views and just add it to your cell if its nil in your `cellForRow`.

Comment: I want to create the common view in storyboard, then where to add/outlet the actions/targets for buttons in common view. is it possible without adding them programatically? also how/where to merge with non identical part of the cell?

Comment: I don't think  you can do in storyboard directly but you can have a look at creating and using xibs, there is plenty of questions regarding the same here. Xibs are essentially individual components of items you can put in a storyboard. I personally just add them programmatically. 

Add to the non-identical part of the cell using the approach who's example i just gave or using xib?

Answer (score 1):

In order to reuse part of the cell i would suggest creating a cell where you will add every part that you have in common between the cells and then subclass that cell to your main cell like this

```
class MyCommonCell: UITableViewCell {

//declare variables init views and other things your tableview cells will have in common

override init() { //do your initialisation here 
   }
}


class MyCell: MyCommonCell { 
//add here the different items from the cell following the same architecture as above
}
```

Edit to answer comment: My question was specific to use common complex uiview, with buttons, actions/targets etc. How can i implement it?

In order to do this then you need to create a class that extens UIView

```
class MyExampleClass: UIView {}
```

and then create a new .xib file that contains a view, this view you can then link to your new MyExampleClass and add outlets to it

Comment: this will be the best practice for your case

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to implement a kind of cell with a colored dot on the left hand side:

First, define your custom cell class:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBInspectable var dotColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        let radius = rect.height / 8
        let center = CGPoint(x: 20, y: rect.midY)

        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.addArc(center: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        context.setFillColor(dotColor.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }
}
```

Now go to Interface Builder and design your prototype cells by changing their class to `MyTableViewCell`:

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: My question was specific to use common complex uiview, with buttons, actions/targets etc. How can i implement it?

Comment: Add these buttons to `MyTableViewCell` and connect action/targets as usual. You need to provide more specifics for me to help you beyond that

Answer (score 0):

I think the response for your question should depend on requirements.

If you want implement panel like in FB

> For example, In Facebook feed, there can be many types of posts. But the like/comment/share panel at the bottom of each post is same. How can I implement these different types of cells keeping like/comment/share panel in a single place on Xcode.

In my opinion you should create small cell with panel. Don't create "big cells". Cell should be as small as possible, reuse will be faster then big cell. Also it will be simplest then "big cell" with subclassing.

So you will have smth like this

```
VideoPost cell
like/comment/share panel cell
ImagePost cell
like/comment/share panel cell
AudioPost cell
like/comment/share panel cell
....
```

And you could easily reuse it in future. Hope it helps you.

Comment: The question is not about small and big cell. Its about how to use identical part with single xib.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create an empty xib and Add UIView component into it. Create a class (Type: UIView Let Suppose "CommonView") add that class with xib and do needed connection, Outlet and Action.

```
Add
var uiview:CommonView?

GOTO :  heightForRowAt{
Set height of cell based on needed calculation.
return height 
}
Then Goto 
cellForRowAt{
 var cell: TableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell.............
// Code for your Xib

 self.uiview?.frame = CGRect(x: cell.dynamicLabel.frame.origin.x  , y: cell.dynamicLabel.frame.origin.y + size + (self.uiview?.frame.size.height)! ,width: (self.uiview?.frame.width)!, height: (self.uiview?.frame.height)!)


self.uiview?.uielementAddedToViewXib///////


cell.contentView.addSubview(self.uiview!)


return cell
}
```

Please check [Code here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rx8lblvmv77ad32/ReusueUIView.zip?dl=0)
Please let me know its working or not.

Comment: Im not the downvoter. I will check the code n let u knw.

Comment: Okay, Actually I did code for this post and somebody downvoted without check.
No problem, It's working for you or not?